# Setup postdata not working for the post that not found

Tags: wordpress

I want to setup custom postdata for single post page. Currently single post page showing `404 not found error`. I am trying to setup postdata from [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action.

Here is my code.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_postdata' );
function set_custom_postdata(){
    global $posts, $wpdb;

    if( isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) && $query->query['post_type'] == 'custom_post_type_name' && isset( $query->query['name'] ) && is_single() && !is_admin() ) {
        wp_reset_postdata();    
        $result = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `wp_custom_table` WHERE `post_name` = %s", esc_sql( $query->query['name'] ) ) );
        $post   = $result;
        setup_postdata( $post );
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me please. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need the `$post = $result;` line, just use `setup_postdata( $result );`. Also, are you sure `$result` is returning a [WP_Post Object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), since that's what [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) requires as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply. No, $result is not returning WP_Post Object, it is simply return a post array. Can we create WP_Post Object manually to pass it in setup_postdata ?

Comment: Hello @Xhynk, I have tried with `WP_Post Object` but no luck. Still facing the same issue. Is there any other way to get it done ?